# Can't see my Ether in mist wallet

Tags: mist, ether

I withdrew Eth from Poloniex to "Account 1" in my Mist Wallet. The transaction shows it being received: https://www.etherchain.org/tx/0x4cfb836eb7a2f870c8d7e60dffec6ede16693a416fc394a8242557f8897223c6

But when I go to my wallet, they're not there
[image: mist image]

I thought I was going to be a Ethereum convert but I've never got stuck like this with Bitcoin.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ethereum Wallet seems to be on the non-hard-forked chain.

From http://fork.ethstats.net/:

[image]

From the image above, taken about 21 minutes after you posted your question, the hard-forked chain is at #1,952,399 and the non-hard-forked chain is at #1,947,977. Your Ethereum Wallet screen shows that your EW instance is at #1,947,895 , consistent with being on the non-hard-forked chain.

If you want to switch Ethereum Wallet from the non-hard-forked chain to the hard-forked chain, select the menu Develop -> "The DAO" Fork -> Support DAO Fork.

Your blockchain may take a while to re-sync to the hard-forked chain.