# Syncing slow to a crawl (2048 blocks in 2 hours)

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I had no issues before, but my syncing has gotten incredibly slow with geth. My system time and date are good (set by ntp) so that shouldn't be the issue and my Internet connexion works fine.

It took 2 hours to get 2048 blocks. Even the highest block parameter is wrong! (as of now, etherchain.org reports that the highest block is 1953411) What gives?

> I0725 18:40:30.199394 core/blockchain.go:972] imported 2048 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 13408 txs in 2h8m18.691083833s. #1888377 [6328a321 / 2ab5bd5c]
>
> eth.syncing
>   {
>     currentBlock: 1889280,
>     highestBlock: 1947463,
>     knownStates: 0,
>     pulledStates: 0,
>     startingBlock: 1849273
>   }

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this, or avoid the issue?

EDIT: running with 1.5.0 seems to be the problem. Downgrading to 1.4.10 fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

You are on the non-forked chain.

From http://fork.ethstats.net/:

[image]

The non-forked chain (Ethereum Classic / ETC) does not have many clients or miners and you would therefore experience the slow syncing.

If you intend to be on the hard-forked chain, you will have to specify the `geth` option:

```
geth --support-dao-fork console
```

If you want to fast sync, you will firstly have to remove your current chain:

```
geth removedb
```

The start the fast sync:

```
geth --support-dao-fork --fast console
```

Also, you will need to be using `geth` v 1.4.10 or above

```
geth version
Geth
Version: 1.4.10-stable
...
```

You can check which chain `geth` is configured to use by typing:

```
geth console
...
I0726 13:16:17.848871 cmd/utils/flags.go:842] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I0726 13:16:17.848917 cmd/utils/flags.go:843] Geth is currently configured to SUPPORT the DAO hard-fork!
I0726 13:16:17.848936 cmd/utils/flags.go:844] You can change your choice prior to block #1920000 with --support-dao-fork or --oppose-dao-fork.
I0726 13:16:17.848955 cmd/utils/flags.go:845] After the hard-fork block #1920000 passed, changing chains requires a resync from scratch!
I0726 13:16:17.848973 cmd/utils/flags.go:846] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See also:

- [Can't see my Ether in mist wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/cant-see-my-ether-in-mist-wallet)
- [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster)

Comment: Oh weird, I thought the latest geth from Ethereum's ppa had the hard fork on by default

Comment: Yes. There is a message "If no fork choice was ever provided, Geth will default to supporting the fork per the majority vote." in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases stating so. If you have chosen `--oppose-dao-fork` in the past, this setting will persist until you change it with the parameter `--support-dao-fork`.

Comment: I have not though. I never ran geth with any flag

Comment: Geth console does not mention anything about being on a certain chain... I'm running 1.5.0

Comment: Ok 1.5.0 is just not working. Downgraded to 1.4.10 and the problem seems to have gone away.