# geth throwing header invalid error all the time

Tags: go-ethereum, logs, nonce, block-header

lately my ethereum node is repeatedly throwing this error:

```
E0811 16:44:00.646126 core/blockchain.go:1128]     uncle[0](30508438) header invalid: nonce for #2004585 [30508438247525b01fa303eb0d417d7a18c69862c18ff7931127152b1db756f1…] is invalid (got 2961809790923137721)
E0811 16:44:00.646097 core/blockchain.go:1127] Bad block #2004591 (0x71249cfe1478a692ad61506201574a997aa9cdccb6a278bd19ea067466e4f88a)
```

I use this command to launch geth:

```
geth --rpc --oppose-dao-fork
```

This is my version:

```
$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.4.10-stable-5f55d95a
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.6.2
OS: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/opt/google/go
```

What does it mean? Why the error? Any fix? Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'm getting this too...making blockchain sync just
drag.....on.....and.....on.....forever...
I tried --fast...this gets a message "blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled."

Comment: You'll have to clear the existing blockchain using `geth removedb` before you can run `geth --support-dao-fork --fast console`. Some further info at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7443/syncing-slow-to-a-crawl-2048-blocks-in-2-hours/7444#7444 .